# Trouble with Laravel Eloquent: How to Retrieve Records from MySQL Table Where Column Value is Case-Insensitive?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project where I need to retrieve records from a MySQL table based on a column value, but I want the search to be case-insensitive. I've tried using the where method in Eloquent, but it seems to be case-sensitive by default.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
$keyword = 'example';
$records = MyModel::where('column_name', $keyword)->get();
```

However, this only retrieves records with an exact case match. How can I modify this query to make it case-insensitive?

I've also looked into the ILIKE operator in raw queries, but I'd prefer a more Laravel-esque approach if possible.

Any help or guidance on achieving a case-insensitive search in Laravel Eloquent with MySQL would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, you can achieve a case-insensitive search using the where method and the `ILIKE` operator. However, since MySQL does not directly support `ILIKE`, you can use the COLLATE `utf8_general_ci` clause to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Here's how you can modify your query to perform a case-insensitive search:

```
$keyword = 'example';
$columnName = 'column_name';

$records = MyModel::where(DB::raw("LOWER($columnName)"), 'LIKE', '%' . strtolower($keyword) . '%')->get();
```

In this example, the `LOWER` function is applied to both the column and the search keyword to make the comparison case-insensitive. The `%` symbols around the keyword in the `LIKE` clause ensure that the keyword can be present anywhere in the column value.

Make sure to import the DB facade at the top of your file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

This approach allows you to perform a case-insensitive search without resorting to raw queries and is more Laravel-esque.

Please adjust the model name (MyModel), column name (column_name), and other details according to your actual code.

Alternative(laravel Way):

```
$records = MyModel::whereRaw(LOWER('column_name LIKE %?%', [strtolower($keyword)])->get();
```

Comment: Yoi do not need to use the like operator at all. Using lower() functiin causes the search to use full table scan as it cannot rely on indexrs any more.